# how to fetch a location from database mysql and pinpoint the locations using markers on google maps

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to fetch locations (just the address. No coordinates) from my database (mysql) and pin them on google map using markers

Answer (score 0):

I come from China, so I use Baidu map. Talk about my development process: the request of Baidu Maps API incoming address, API will return to the coordinates, the coordinates of the third party jquery. Similar picture effect  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaQ7R.jpg)